# Excel functions IF()

Tags: excel, vba

I've become a little rusty with excel. Haven't used it since college - am currently working on a project and cannot figure some things out. I have a spreadsheet and I have about 2000 records. In one of my columns i have values of either 0 or 1. I'm trying to do a simple function..

```
=if(Currentcell=0,"N","Y")
```

What I'm trying to do is put the formunla inside the cell with the 0 or 1, so that I don't need to create another column with the result. Is this possible?

Comment: No, most formulas cannot refer to themselves.

Comment: Do it in the next column over then copy/paste back to original?

Comment: You could do it in a different column and hide the other column that you don't want displayed.

Comment: If This is all you want you can do a custom format of `"Y";;"N"`, It will not change the underlying number but will show "Y" for any positive number and "N" for `0`.

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah, basically its 0 or 1, so if it's 0 then show me "N" or if anything else then "Y", how would this function look. Post as answer so i can accept it

Comment: I found another way of doing this. I'm pulling this data from SQL server, so I'm doing a CASE statement where i say ......case when number='0' then 'N' else 'Y' end as Number1

Comment: Yes fixing the data before it gets to excel is the best.

Comment: You could just select the column and do a find/replace; or, you could use a filter to view just the 0's then 1's and copy/paste the N's and Y's. Either options is about a 20 second process

Comment: True story. Thanks for that. I guess I didn't think of that - to be honest. I went with the query and it looks good!

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way for accessing your current cell. It will ultimately result in circular references.

I will suggest that instead of using formula, use conditional formatting as it provides a visual impact on the value in the cell. 
So just add following conditions -

1) If value in cell is 0 then format cell as RED color.

2) If value in a cell is 1, you can change the format to GREEN color.

3) If value in the cell is less than 0 OR greater than 1, then format cell as BLANK

I hope this helps.

Comment: it does result in circular reference -- this is why i'm formatting it straight outta SQL. I figured i could do it inside the cell itself but guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help. Because I was grabbing this info from SQL SERVER and then pasting it into excel - i decided to instead do a case statement before I copy the data into excel, so i have something along the lines.

```
select Fname, Lname, Age, Case When Number ='0' then 'N' else 'Y' end as NumberXX
from tblClientInfo
```

It works like a charm!